# Libsass: Error: "env(safe-area-inset-right)" is not a number for `max'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, sass-rails

I am able to precompile assets in my Rails app. But when I start server and hit url. I get this error[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't parse that CSS file, because it is CSS and not SASS. And CSS has its own min/max functions, see https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/